# Trying to insert values from one table to another where a surrogate key match is not found

Tags: mysql, left-join, bulkinsert, right-join

I am trying to simulate a full outer join, comparing two tables against each other. The batch_import table contains records that need to be inserted, only if they don't exist in the employees table. To do this I have tried the following query:

```
INSERT INTO employees (forename, surname, employersId, custom_corpore_headOffice, contractId)
SELECT firstname, surname, employeenumber, dob, store, contractId
FROM batch_import
LEFT JOIN employees ON batch_import.employeenumber = employees.employersId AND batch_import.contractId = employees.contractId
UNION ALL
SELECT forename, surname, employersId, custom_corpore_headOffice, contractId
FROM batch_import RIGHT JOIN employees ON batch_import.employeenumber = employees.employersId AND batch_import.contractId = employees.contractId
WHERE batch_import.employeenumber IS NULL AND batch_import.contractId IS NULL
                       ";
```

however when I run this query I get the message back from mysql: ERROR 1137 (HY000): Can't reopen table: 'batch_import'

I am guessing it is the logic of my UNION ALL being incorrect. Could someone please help me find a solution?

EDIT:: I have tried this query and it keeps adding records onto the table, starting at the last record. I have also tried:

```
                    INSERT INTO employees (forename, surname, employersId, dateOfBirth, custom_corpore_headOffice, contractId)
                SELECT firstname, batch_import.surname, employeenumber, dob, store, batch_import.contractId
                FROM batch_import
                LEFT JOIN employees ON batch_import.employeenumber = employees.employersId AND batch_import.contractId = employees.contractId
                UNION
                SELECT firstname, batch_import.surname, employeenumber, dob, store, batch_import.contractId
                FROM batch_import RIGHT JOIN employees ON batch_import.employeenumber = employees.employersId AND batch_import.contractId = employees.contractId;
```

but still to no avail. Instead of ignoring what exists it simply writes everything to the end of the table.

Also tried: `INSERT INTO employees (forename, surname, employersId, dateOfBirth, custom_corpore_headOffice, contractId)
                    SELECT firstname, batch_import.surname, employeenumber, dob, store, batch_import.contractId
                    FROM batch_import
                    LEFT JOIN employees ON employees.employersId = NULL;`

Comment: I have found out that ERROR 1137 (HY000): Can't reopen table: 'batch_import could be thrown because batch_import is a temporary table

Comment: Glad you found the issue. The logic looks correct; you can also use UNION and then you won't need the where clause as UNION will return only distinct values.

Comment: Hmm it seems to be adding the data to the end of the existing data in the database.

Comment: Ok, so you are not really looking for a full join. You just need the left join where employees.employersId is null.

Comment: Really appreciate the help Jayvee, I have amended the query like so:
                    INSERT INTO employees (forename, surname, employersId, dateOfBirth, custom_corpore_headOffice, contractId)
                    SELECT firstname, batch_import.surname, employeenumber, dob, store, batch_import.contractId
                    FROM batch_import
                    LEFT JOIN employees ON employees.employersId = NULL; but i am getting the same result as before, i am totally baffled. the data in batch_import is exactly the same as in the employes table so it should not write anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OPTION 1

```
INSERT INTO employees (forename, surname, employersId, custom_corpore_headOffice, contractId)
SELECT firstname, surname, employeenumber, dob, store, contractId
FROM batch_import
WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select 1 From employees where batch_import.employeenumber = employees.employersId AND batch_import.contractId = employees.contractId)
```

OPTION 2

```
INSERT INTO employees (forename, surname, employersId, custom_corpore_headOffice, contractId)
SELECT firstname, surname, employeenumber, dob, store, contractId
FROM batch_import
LEFT JOIN employees ON batch_import.employeenumber = employees.employersId AND batch_import.contractId = employees.contractId
WHERE employees.employersId is NULL
```

Comment: You are officially my hero. I am not worthy